# Why will the CSS file not be attached when I use absolute path?

Tags: php, html, css, path, routes

Here is my code:

```
<link href="<?= realpath(__DIR__ . '/..') ?>/css/styles-home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The result is:

```
<link href="C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\ltk/css/styles-home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Why that css file doesn't attach to the HTML page? I mean I don't see styles in HTML page. Noted that the path is right. Since when I open the following path through the browser:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/myweb/ltk/css/styles-home.css
```

I can see CSS codes. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console.

Comment: `href` attributes hold urls, not filepaths. That is not a valid url.

Comment: Your result href contains different slashes (\ and /)

Comment: @Steve Ok, is this valid? `C:/xampp/htdocs/myweb/ltk/css/styles-home.css`

Comment: no, whats your pages url, something like `http://localhost/mypage.php`?

Comment: @Steve `http://localhost/myweb/ltk/css/styles-home.css`.

Comment: Then a valid url is `http://localhost/myweb/ltk/css/styles-home.css` or a relative url `/myweb/ltk/css/styles-home.css`

Comment: From what i know access to system drives like c:/ d:/ is denied. Its a security risk. Css and Javascript lies in browser public dir and thats where the url should point to. I would do it like $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/public/css/file.css' etc

Comment: @Steve, there's nothing wrong with using a file uri for the href attribute.  The point here is that the file uri is in the wrong format.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: @MartinAJ ,how are you accessing the web page that contains the link to the CSS?  Is it via a web server, php or what exactly?  Please give us details of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a html file that contains an image element with an src with a file path similar to what you have above.

```
<img src="C:\foo\bar.jpg">
```

And I access the file over http (here my local web server has the html file in the document root) through Google Chrome (a web browser).  The browser resolves the path to:

```
http://localhost/C:/foo/bar.jpg
```

If however I open the file (via the file system) in the browser it tries:

```
file:///var/www/C:/foo/bar.jpg
```

My document root being `/var/www`.

You can see that the browser is treating the image path here as a relative one.